# How to install php7.4, 5.6 ubuntu 21.10

Tags: php, php7, 21.10

How to install the old version of PHP.
It does not work at the moment repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then:

```
The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on “it does not work”? Does this mean Apache is not rendering the PHP? Or does this mean you cannot install 7.4 specifically? Do you see any error messages?

Comment: i've tried the answer from [Tadeáš Fryčák](https://askubuntu.com/a/1369856/1494720) and it works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had similar problem and I solved it by:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-impish.list
```

then replacing `impish` (Ubuntu 21.10) with `focal` (Ubuntu 20.04) on the first line in the file to this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ focal main
```

and then

```
sudo apt install php5.6
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. If you have php 8 and want to install another version ex: 7.4 it will conflict some libraries... I hope ondrej will add the repo for ubuntu 21.10

Comment: I agree, but as a temporary fix, it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than edit or change the above answers I wanted to mention that the PPA supports 21.10 now.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

You can install multiple version of PHP with this PPA.  But by default 8 is in the repos, but if you need older versions this PPA will solve that problem.

It should be noted that this PPA outlines a few things noted below.
CAVEATS:

1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
3. If you are using nginx, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
      or ppa:ondrej/nginx

Just to be extra helpful here, if you need to change the default PHP version use this command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! No longer a need for the work around in the original answer tagged as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the [mentioned PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) does not provide packages for Ubuntu 21.10. You have to disable it by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r -y ppa:ondrej/php
```

and then use [PHP 8.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libapache2-mod-php) from official repositories.

To get your simple PHP page rendered by Apache use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
sudo service apache2 restart

cat << EOF | sudo tee /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
EOF
```

and then navigate your web-browser to `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` .